# Multi Device Hybrid Apps on debugging using Ripple Emulator does not open chrome

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I have created a blank project using Visual Studio 2013 CTP version for Multi Device Hybrid App template. When I run the project for Android platform using Ripple Nexus Galaxy, it does not open the chrome. The output window displays a message that Deployment succeeded. But does not really open the browser window.

Is there a configuration that I need to look at?

Comment: Since your build/deployment succeeded, make sure that your windows firewall is not blocking Ripple on public or open networks by following the steps mentioned in the [FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn727288)

Comment: I have the same issue, either it does not open chrome at all or it opens chrome but page is not loaded. It's not about firewall

Comment: Avani, it did not help. I tried disabling the Windows Firewall. No luck!!!

Comment: There have been issues similar to what you describe where Chrome does not launch when deploying to Ripple.  Chrome may have become corrupted in some way.  Please try re-installing Chrome to see if that addresses the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When this issue occurs, what works is to exit Visual Studio, kill any Chrome processes from the task manager, and reboot the machine.  Resuming your work in a new instance of VS should allow you to successfully deploy to Ripple.