# chrome not working with ripple nexus s and galaxy android multidevice hybrid app

Tags: google-chrome, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I have created a blank project using Visual Studio 2013 update 3 CTP 2 version for Multi Device Hybrid App template. When I run the project for Android platform using Ripple Nexus s and nexus Galaxy, it does not open the chrome . When I press f5 build and deployment gets succeed and after that a message dialog appears saying : 
          object reference not set to an instance of an object

The output window displays a message that Deployment succeeded. But does not really open the browser window.

I had reinstalled the template twice. Also I had turned my firewall off for public network but I couldn't Ensure Domain, Private, and Public are all checked for “Evented I/O for V8 JavaScript.”  .Below is the o/p window.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp3, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0 \ TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : 
The TypeScript Compiler was given no files     for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  C:\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.31 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\tjdvfq0n.lk1\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp3
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ App dir C:\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3\bld\Debug already exists
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: 
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins: 
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins: 
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "BlankCordovaApp3"
1>  no icon found matching Android typical densities
1>  no icon found matching Android typical densities
1>  no icon found matching Android typical densities
1>  no icon found matching Android typical densities
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.BlankCordovaApp3"
2>------ Deploy started: Project: BlankCordovaApp3, Configuration: Debug Android ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

When this issue occurs, what works is to exit Visual Studio, kill any Chrome processes from the task manager, and reboot the machine. Resuming your work in a new instance of VS should allow you to successfully deploy to Ripple. An earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383681/multi-device-hybrid-apps-on-debugging-using-ripple-emulator-does-not-open-chrome) covers the same issue.

Comment: thanks ma'am Ellen for your response... actually i tried this but nothing worked. Is there any other solution for this??

Comment: @Amit - Does reinstalling Chrome fix it?

Comment: Howdy ma'am  Ellen .I did that couple of times ,but it did n't worked.I 'm using windows 8.1 single language and installing chrome for windows 8 .Is this a issue ??

Comment: @ma'am ellen -can u specify which process to kill in task manager.I couldn't find a process having a chrome icon.

Comment: The process would be named chrome.exe.  This issue is actively being investigated.

Comment: @ ma'am Ellen - plz tell me some solution as soon as possible .I have to  submit a  project based on this. Also i 'm unable to get .apk file in a bin/android folder...

Comment: ma'am ellen - recently i have got a dialog box saying : Google chrome cannot read and write to its data directory ,though the build was succeed. with that chrome is opening but with link :localhost:4400/__vs_to_ripple__/index.html?_enablerripple=corodova-3.0.0-nexusS but the page is not available ...

Comment: @Amit - refer to the response to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533088/google-chrome-cant-read-and-write-to-its-data-directory-mutli-device-hybrid-app) to address your latest Chrome issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio as an administrator and try again.