# Google chrome can't read and write to its data directory mutli-device hybrid app

Tags: google-chrome, multi-device-hybrid-apps

On running the  ripple emulator with nexus s & galaxy . I am getting a dialog box saying

```
Google chrome can't read and write to its data directory
c:\ users\amit
```

and when i click ok on that .suddenly chrome opens up saying : cannot view webpage .
one more thing where can i set the System path variable to

```
          %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

I mean to say what is this(System path variable) i don't understand .

Comment: The system path refers to the Path variable that is part of your System ( not User) environment variables on Windows.

Comment: @Avani- Howdy...thanks for ur response .what i 'm asking is that Environment variable can be set by going in              vs>tools>option>Environment variable..... Similarly how to set the path variable to above mention path...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google`
2. Right-click on the "Chrome" folder
3. Go to the "Security" tab
4. Click on "Edit..." button -> "Add..."
5. Type `Everyone` -> "OK" -> "OK"
6. Click on "Advanced"
7. At the end of the "Owner" field, click on blue "Change" word
8. Type `Everyone` -> "OK" -> "OK" -> "OK"

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Windows 7.

Go to the file given in the error message:

```
c\users\[username]\application data\local\google\chrome
```

- right click the chrome file
- share with-specific people
- use drop down arrow in top box and choose your username ie give yourself permission to share the file.
- add
- confirm.

Message says its been done,

- close.

Chrome then opens without having to open it as administrator after every boot-up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Chrome user data directory might be corrupted, try following and see whether it helps:

1. Take the back-up of bookmarks (if you want to back-up the data)
2. Delete C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome folder
3. Uninstall Chrome
4. Reinstall Chrome

Comment: @ Abhishek- Thanks for ur response .I tried the above mentioned things ....but it did not worked.

Comment: @Amit- please email vscordovatools@microsoft.com so I can arrange to get more detailed information to understand the root cause of this.

Comment: @ Ellen -ma'am you didn't respond to my email.Plz show your interest in this .

Comment: @ Ellen - ma'am what happened ??

Comment: @Amit - per my response to your email, the issue looks to be due to our tooling not properly handling user names that contain spaces, as yours does.  We are working on addressing this issue but in the meantime the only workaround is to create an alternate account with no spaces in the name and work from that account.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, you can create a android emulator. You don't need chrome for that.

Answer (score 0):

It will work normally when you log in as administrator. If not you can simply change the "chmod" of the directory to 777. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

*I was facing this same issue for months, and now I have solved it.*

1. First uninstall Chrome then go to `C:\Program Files` to double-check and hence delete the 'Google' folder if it still remains.
2. Then press `Windows+R` and type in `regedit` to enter into Registry Editor.
3. Now locate `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google` and **delete** the Google folder. *In case you don't find the folder, just delete any Google folder you come across under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software`*
4. Almost Done! Now download Chrome from it's website, install it and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the dialog point to the specific folder. Then I go to the SystemTemp and grant the permission as well as uncheck "Read-only" option.
This work for me without re-install nor delete register key.

[image]